# Using a select max(blah) as an input parameter

Tags: postgresql

This may be a naive question, but is it possible to use a select max(blah) to update a parameter in an input statement?

input a,b,c into table1 values (10, 20, (select max(c) where a=10) + 1) for example?

I tried this in postgresql and got the hint

```
insert into "MeterData".data(nmi, intervalend, "E1", version) values
('E1234', now(), 12.4, (select max(version) where nmi = 'E1234' and interalend = now()) + 1)

ERROR:  column "version" does not exist
LINE 2: ('E1234', now(), 12.4, (select max(version) where nmi = 'E12...
                                           ^
HINT:  There is a column named "version" in table "data", but it cannot be referenced from this part of the query.
SQL state: 42703
Character: 105
```

I'm not even sure if this is possible. The idea is that if the entry already exists in the table, I need to add the new data and update the version by 1.

Hope this makes sense.

Thanks to the help here, I've got this working now IF there is a value in version to start with, however, if there is no value yet, it sets to null and so doesn't increment on subsequent calls. I've tried setting a default value on that column to 1 (thought that would have done it, but no), and tried a few different ways unsuccessfully to get the query something like

```
insert into "MeterData".data(nmi, intervalend, "E1", version) values
('E1234', '2021-02-08 00:00:00+11', 12.4, (select max(d.version) from "MeterData".data d where d.nmi = 'E1234' and d.intervalend = '2021-02-08 00:00:00+11') into value, case value==null then 1, else value+1 end))
```

but that just ends badly.

Is there a way to do this, or do I need to write a function to handle this (or do it in some other code external to the db?

I have no idea why this question was closed.. what the??? How is this not a relevant question?

Comment: You are fetching `max(version)` from nowhere. Try to add a `from` clause.

Comment: `interalend = now()` seems rather dubious given the fact that `now()` has a resolution of microseconds

Comment: The question was closed because it is not general enough that anybody else than you would benefit from the answer. At least that's what I guess - I didn't vote on the question.

Comment: What @LaurenzAlbe said. And also you had `select max(...) where ...` which was never ever going to work which influenced early reviewers to vote to close. Right now the question is very unclear; probably best to open a new one with just the actual problem you have now.

Comment: PS `coalesce(..., 1)` may help you for the first time.

Comment: Thanks @Colin 't Hart... that did the trick, and explains the vote downs.. happy days.

Answer (score 1):

As the comments state, you forgot to include the `FROM` clause in your `SELECT` query. Try this:

```
insert into "MeterData".data(nmi, intervalend, "E1", version) values
('E1234', now(), 12.4, (select max(version) from MeterData where nmi = 'E1234' and interalend = now()) + 1)
```

Comment: So close....

insert into "MeterData".data(nmi, intervalend, "E1", version) values
('E1234', '2021-02-08 00:00:00+10', 12.4, (select max(d.version) from "MeterData".data d where d.nmi = 'E1234' and d.intervalend = '2021-02-08 00:00:00+10') + 1) works once the first entry is set to 1. However, if the entry isn't in the table, version stays null and so the counter doesn't work... how do I set it to 1 the first time?